# I am getting Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: null has no properties in apexchart| Vue, Apexchart

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, apexcharts

I'm am getting  the following error when I try switching between views

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: null has no properties
    create apexcharts.common.js:6
    screenCTM apexcharts.common.js:6
    toParent apexcharts.common.js:6
    ungroup apexcharts.common.js:6
    each apexcharts.common.js:6
    ungroup apexcharts.common.js:6
    ungroup apexcharts.common.js:6
    each apexcharts.common.js:6
    ungroup apexcharts.common.js:6
    value apexcharts.common.js:14
```

the graph itself is  basic, the only differnce from tutorial graph is that it receives two props from another component

```js
<template>
  <div>
     <apexchart
      width="500"
      type="line"
      :options="chartOptions"
      :series="series"
    ></apexchart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";

export default {
    name:'Graf',
    components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts, 
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          id: "graf",
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [],
        },
        atUnmount() {
          this.chartOptions.xaxis.categories=[],
          this.series=[]
        },
        
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "series",
          data: [],
        },
        
      ] 
        };
    },
    props:{ 
         data: Array,
         timestamp:Array
     },
    async created() {

      this.chartOptions.xaxis.categories=this.timestamp
      this.series=[{data: this.data}]
      
    }
      
}
</script>
```

The problem seems to go away when I reload the page so I'm looking for a way to fix this or to find a workaround

this is my JSON data
this is my JSON

```
"uredjaji": [{
            "id": 1,
            "startDate": "03 03 2021 13:49:51.141",
            "endDate": "",
            "kalibracija": false,
            "active": true,
            "senzori": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "timestamp": [
                        1613967677332,
                        1613967677338,
                        1613967677341
                    ],
                    "calibrtionTimestamp": [
                        1213967677231,
                        1213967677237,
                        1213967677240
                    ],
                    "calibrationData": [
                        0,
                        1,
                        0
                    ],
                    "data": [
                        12,
                        20,
                        15
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "timestamp": [
                        1613967677231,
                        1613967677235,
                        1613967677240
                    ],
                    "calibrtionTimestamp": [
                        1213967677231,
                        1213967677237,
                        1213967677240
                    ],
                    "calibrationData": [
                        0,
                        2,
                        0
                    ],
                    "data": [
                        15.5,
                        15.1,
                        15.7
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "startDate": "1 04 2021 12:39:41.141",
            "endDate": "25 05 2021 13:29:21.141",
            "kalibracija": false,
            "active": false,
            "senzori": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "timestamp": [],
                    "calibrtionTimestamp": [
                        1613967677232,
                        1613967677238,
                        1613967677241
                    ],
                    "calibrationData": [
                        0,
                        3,
                        1
                    ],
                    "data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "timestamp": [],
                    "calibrtionTimestamp": [
                        1613967677229,
                        1613967677232,
                        1613967677238
                    ],
                    "calibrationData": [
                        0,
                        2,
                        1
                    ],
                    "data": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "senzori": [{
            "id": 1,
            "timestamp": [
                1613967677332,
                1613967677338,
                1613967677341
            ],
            "calibrtionTimestamp": [
                1213967677231,
                1213967677237,
                1213967677240
            ],
            "calibrationData": [
                0,
                1,
                0
            ],
            "data": [
                12,
                20,
                15
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "timestamp": [],
            "calibrtionTimestamp": [
                1613967677232,
                1613967677238,
                1613967677241
            ],
            "calibrationData": [
                0,
                3,
                1
            ],
            "data": []
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "timestamp": [
                1613967677231,
                1613967677235,
                1613967677240
            ],
            "calibrtionTimestamp": [
                1213967677231,
                1213967677237,
                1213967677240
            ],
            "calibrationData": [
                0,
                2,
                0
            ],
            "data": [
                15.5,
                15.1,
                15.7
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "timestamp": [],
            "calibrtionTimestamp": [
                1613967677229,
                1613967677232,
                1613967677238
            ],
            "calibrationData": [
                0,
                2,
                1
            ],
            "data": []
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the structure of `data` and `timestamp`?

Comment: will edit it now

Comment: Add a new data property something like `isDataReady` with value as `false`. In template add a v-if to this `isDataReady`. In created after you set the chart options, set `isDataReady` to true. This might make it work.

Comment: @Keerthi Kumar P didn't help .. I'l ltry to provide more details in the post

Comment: @PeopleCallMeLucifer The `JSON` you added, which one is for `data: Array` and which for `timestamp: Array`?

Comment: @Fabalance I have two graphs per component one gets the calibrationTimestamp and calibrationData arrays and the other gets the regular timestamp and timestamp arrays

Comment: @PeopleCallMeLucifer Okay. Can you show how you pass those `props` to the component?